# GCC builds under teamcity docker agent

Tags: docker, gcc, centos, teamcity

I'm trying out teamcity to build GCC binaries with docker agents on centos. I setup a docker agent to connect to builder2 TC server.

```
$ docker pull jetbrains/teamcity-agent
$ mkdir -p /mnt/builders/teamcity/agent1/conf
$ mkdir -p /mnt/builders/teamcity/agent/work
$ mkdir -p /mnt/builders/teamcity/agent/system


docker run -it --name agent1  \
    -e SERVER_URL="http://builder2:8111" \
    -e AGENT_NAME="builder2_agent1" \
    --hostname builder2_agent \
    --dns="xx.xxx.xx.xx" \
    -v /mnt/builders/teamcity/agent1/conf:/data/teamcity_agent/conf  \
    -v /mnt/builders/teamcity/agent/work:/opt/buildagent/work  \
    -v /mnt/builders/teamcity/agent/system:/opt/buildagent/system  \
    --network='BuilderNetwork' \
    jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

All that works good but in order to make a build you must import the devtoolset like this

```
scl enable devtoolset-10 "/bin/bash"
$ which make
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/bin/make
```

So how is this done with docker agent? Are these tools to be built in the image or do you expose the `/opt/rh` dir to the container?  Also if you were to expose the volume then how do you install `/usr/bin/scl` (i.e rh package `scl-utils-20130529-19.el7.x86_64`) into the docker container? Does it even make sense to run an agent in docker for this?

Comment: Imagine you have a _separate computer_ running whatever `jetbrains/teamcity-agent` is. Completely different separate workstation, with separate monitor and keyboard. How do you think would you answer your questions then?

Comment: @KamilCuk i would normally install the components via yum but that does not exist in the container image.

Comment: Yes, _on your computer_ you would. There are [many package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager#Comparison_of_commands). As noted, imagine it's a separate computer, like your friends, and you have to figure that out. You can inspect Dockerfile used to create the image to get what linux distribution is it based on. Or you can just test.

Comment: @KamilCuk  I'm well aware of all the package managers. the container is the same arch as the host centos7 but there is simply no rpm to install anything.  My question is more about how teamcity specifically should be setup for a docker agent in this case not about packaging in general.

Comment: `the container is the same arch as the host centos7` Are you __sure__? Also, a architecture is not a Linux distribution. `there is simply no rpm to install anything` Please post the code. `jetbrains/teamcity-agent` is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, installing scl-tools on ubuntu makes little sense. `how do you install /usr/bin/scl into the docker container?` Just like _anywhere_ else. If you do not  have a packge available in package repositories, you install from source. Or convert rpm to .deb. . Source seems available here https://github.com/sclorg/scl-utils .

Comment: @KamilCuk My code is posted with the question and again the question aimed at people who are aware of how to setup GCC building on centos with docker container.